# How to check set_fact in molecule?

Tags: ansible, molecule

I've created a simple task which creates a fact (new variable):

```yaml
---
- name: Define internal user based on prefix
  set_fact:
    role_user_uid: "{{ lookup('vars', '{{ user_prefix }}_uid', default='') }}"
```

where `user_prefix` is defined in *defaults/* as `user_prefix: "ansible"`.

How can I create a test which checks that `user_prefix` has a specific value?

I've tried via *testinfra*

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def AnsibleVars(host):
    all_vars = host.ansible.get_variables()
    return all_vars

def test_user_exists(host,AnsibleVars):
    print(AnsibleVars)
    var_prefix = AnsibleVars['user_prefix']
```

and via *ansible* provider:

```yaml
- name: "test default user"
  assert:
    that:
      user_prefix == "ansible"
```

but I get errors that `user_prefix` is note defined.

I did enable `gather_facts: yes` in *verify.yml*

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but, you have the _'mustache do not stack'_ issue, so, in your case: `"{{ lookup('vars', user_prefix ~ '_uid', default='') }}"`

Comment: You can only check a role's var default value if that role is included in the current play.

Comment: @Zeitounator but I have `user_prefix` defined in defaults and the tests give errors :(

Comment: The test is done in molecule after you have played your role, not during role execution

Comment: @Zeitounator :( So the only way I can think to test is to write the variable in a yml file and load that file in the test. Or... move the tests as subsequent tasks in 'converge.yml'?

Comment: Or load the default/main.yaml file and test. I don't think there's actually much added value to this. Role's defaults are highly overridable by nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I handle this is to save all `vars` to a `.yml` file at the end of the `converge` stage, so I can then later perform `pytest` tests based on the state of variables when `converge` completes.

The task to do this is placed in the `converge.yml` file for the scenario:

```
  post_tasks:
    - name: Dump all variables used to converge for later use.
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: |
          {{ vars | to_yaml }}
        dest: /tmp/ansible-vars.yml
        mode: 0o600
      changed_when: false
      delegate_to: localhost
```

To access these variables during `pytest` tests, do something along the lines of:

```
import os
import testinfra.utils.ansible_runner
import pytest
import yaml


with open('/tmp/ansible-vars.yml', 'r') as yaml_file:
    ansible_vars = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)


def get_homedir(host=None, user=None):
    """Get user's home directory path in instance."""
    cmd = host.run(f'/usr/bin/getent passwd {user}')
    return cmd.stdout.split(':')[5]


@pytest.fixture(params=ansible_vars.get('accounts', []))
def fixture_users(request):
    return request.param


def test_bashrc_sources_aliases(host, fixture_users):
    user = fixture_users
    homedir = get_homedir(host=host, user=user)
    f = host.file(os.path.join(homedir, '.bashrc'))
    assert f.exists
    assert f.user == user
    assert r'. ~/.bash_aliases' in f.content_string
```

Not perfect, but DRY and avoids hard-coding and coupling of tasks to tests.

Don't forget to add this to the `cleanup` stage:

```
    - name: Delete variables saved from converge step.
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /tmp/ansible-vars.yml
        state: absent
      changed_when: false
      delegate_to: localhost
```

If anyone has a better way to do this, chime in! :)